# image link inside .css file OR call a controller using .js file in laravel

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4

How can I add a link to a image inside a .css or .js file.

If I put a relative path like that:

```
background-image: url("../assets/images/assets.png");
```

it will load the file only if my view is like that

```
/mysite/users
```

if the url of my view change from

```
/mysite/users
```

to

```
/mysite/users/job/10/something
```

It will not load.

I can put the full path like that:

```
    background-image: url("/mysite/assets/images/assets.png");
```

but if I have to create a copy of this site like 'theSite', I will have to open All my css files and .js file and replace /mysite to /theSite

Are there a smarty way to do that? like I use in the view:

```
{{ URL::to('style.css') }}
```

.

```
EDITED
```

The ceejayoz is correct.

But if you need a .js file that call a Controller you could do this:

create this route:

```
Route::get('/js/custom.js ', function()
{

    $contents = View::make('js/custom');
    $response = Response::make($contents, 200);
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
    return $response;
});
```

create the custom.blade.php view and put this js content:

```
$('#inputX').change(function() {
    $.ajax({                                      
            url: "{{URL::to('track/data')}}",
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            async: sync,                         
            data: {
                doit: $('#inputX').val()
            },
            success: function(data)          
            {       
                console.log(data)
            }
    });     

});
```

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URLs in CSS files are relative to the CSS file, not the page it's used on. It should not matter what the URL of the page you're on is - if your CSS is in `public/css` and you use `../images/something.jpg`, it'll use `public/images/something.jpg` regardless of the URL of the page.